# Display modal popup with some text after click on Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

How can I can display modal popup with some text clicking on Hyperlink. I would link use Ajax with ASP.net 4.0. I am new to ASP.NET 4.0. Please advise!

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/

Asp does not have anything to do with it, since it is only client side.

Comment: Thanks. We are not using JQuery in our project. I am trying to  display data from the database column value.